# Resize images before upload to server with javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload

I have some researched on the subject which I am asking about, but I could not find what I needed.

in Html side there is the code below.By the way, the code is written in angular.

```
<input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)" accept=".jpg,.gif,.png" multiple="multiple">
```

in `onChange` method, I am sending the request to `makeFileRequest` method.

```
onChange(event: any) {
    var files = event.srcElement.files;
    this.apiModel.makeFileRequest(`${API_URL"/PostImage"}`, [], files).subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log("all files uploaded");
    });
}
```

the `makeFileRequest` method is sending the files to server.This code is working fine.

```
public makeFileRequest(url: string, params: string[], files: File[]): Observable<Response> {
          return Observable.create((observer:any) => {
               let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
                  xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();


              for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
               }

              xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                      if (xhr.status === 200) {
                          observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                          observer.complete();
                      } else {
                        if (xhr.status == 401) {
                          this.authService.logout();
                          this.router.navigate(['login']);
                         } 
                          observer.error(xhr.response);
                      }
                  }
              };

              xhr.open('POST', url, true);
              xhr.send(formData);
          });
      }
```

But I think I must do what I need inside the below code to resize images.

```
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
}
```

Can you please suggest me a way to solve my question?

Comment: Use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read image data from files first and then use some of many existing libraries to resize images and then post image as `base64` to server

Comment: is it possible to make this without  converting base64?

Comment: Nope. The only way to save image edited by browser is to get base64 source and to send it on a server